# Regarding so and very

Tags: intensifiers

As we use **so** before adjective like "the movie is so interesting," but can I say negative way like "the movie is not so interesting" means I want to say someone the movie not good?

Comment: Yes, you can say that. For future questions, you may prefer to ask on our sister site, [ELL.se], which is dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language. Despite its name, this site is for more academic questions of English than practical ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable.

> "That movie was *so* boring!"
>   "Really?  I thought it was not *so* bad."
>
> "This dress looks *so* tight on you.  Isn't it uncomfortable?"
>   "No, it's not so uncomfortable."

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct, the problem is

> so not
>   not so

are not commutative.

> The movie is **so interesting**.
>   *the movie has a* ***high degree*** *of being interesting*.
>
> The movie is **not so** interesting.
>   *the movie has a* ***low degree*** *of being interesting*.
>
> The movie is **so not** interesting.
>   The movie is **so uninteresting**.
>   *the movie has a* ***high degree*** *of being uninteresting*.